# Using count with group without distinct elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
select id1, id2 from myTable

id1      id2
1        100
2        100          
3        100          
3        400          
4        200
```

I want to count how many times each case of `id1` occurs, while retaining all cases of `id2` in the second column such that I receive the following table:

```
id1      id2      count
1        100          1
2        100          1
3        100          2
3        400          2
4        200          1
```

The following query gives the correct count, but only shows distinct elements of `id1`, thus it doesn't retain all cases of `id2`

```
select id1, id2, count(id1) from myTable
group by id1

id1      id2      count
1        100          1
2        100          1
3        100          2
4        200          1
```

Instead I tried this query, to group by both columns, which retains all of the information, but does not give the count I desire:

```
select id1, id2, count(id1) from myTable
group by id1, id2

id1      id2      count
1        100          1
2        100          1
3        100          1
3        400          1
4        200          1
```

This feels like it should be extremely simple. Can this be done in a single query, or must I use a subquery? If so, what would the subquery look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select id1, id2, 
       (select count(*) from mytable as t2 where t1.id1 = t2.id1) "count"
from mytable as t1
```

By using a subselect as a column result, you can build your desire structure in output.

Comment: verry inefficient :(

Comment: @TedFilippidis, please, explain why. So then, i can improve my code;

Comment: This is probably the best solution in MySQL.

Comment: @abe, a sub query is always more SGA / Processing /Slownless

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.count
FROM
    test.id a,
    (SELECT 
        id1, COUNT(id1) AS count
    FROM
        test.id
    GROUP BY id1) b
WHERE
    a.id1 = b.id1;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
select id1, id2, count(id1)  OVER (PARTITION BY id1) from myTable
```

Comment: Hey Ted, I'm getting a syntax error when I try to run this. Does this work with mySQL?

Comment: @Lance_P you may be right I kind of an oracle guy,sorry! Although mySQL is an Oracle Product now and I am trying to catch up!